# Update nested array ES6, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have the following array of objects:

```js
[{
  idChatPublic: "1",
  message: "hello",
  chatLike: [{
    id: "1",
    idChatPublic: "1"
  }]
}]
```

What I want is simply add a new object into chatLike array.
Here is my attempt, but it doesn't seem to be working whats wrong with this piece of code?

```js
async function sendLike(messageId: string) {
  const newLike = {
    idChatPublic: messageId,
  }

  mutateMessages(
    (data) => {
      console.log(data) // returns the array I want to update
      data.map((message) => {
        if (message.idChatPublic === messageId) {
          console.log(message.chatLike) // returns the array inside the object I want to update
          return {
            ...message,
            chatLike: [...message.chatLike, newLike]
          }
        } else {
          return message
        }
      })
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: *"doesn't seem to be working"* is not a good problem statement. Explain what the problem is, what was expected, what you got instead.

Comment: when you using the spread operator in message it return the whole data include chatLink do it by add to constant and push the new link and the return it like this const myMessage = {...message}; myMessage.push(newLink); return myMessage;

Comment: @AbdelrhmanMohamed Hi my friend that was exactly the problem my method was right but I wasn't return anything.

Comment: @DiegoBraga did you mean when you call the sendLike() function returning data or it's not adding the newLike to chatLike array, to be clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

Probably, you have to create const with new array and return it:

```js
const newData = data.map((message) => {
  if (message.idChatPublic === messageId) {
    console.log(message.chatLike) // returns the array inside the object I want to update
    return {
      ...message,
      chatLike: [...message.chatLike, newLike]
    }
  } else {
    return message
  }
});

return newData;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `map()`. I think you can do that like this:

```js
async function sendLike(messageId: string) {

 const newLike = {
   idChatPublic: messageId,
 };
 
 mutateMessages((data) => {
   data.forEach((message) => {
     if (message.idChatPublic === messageId) {
       message.chatLike.push(newLike);
     }
   }
 });
 
}
```

Loop throw your objects array with `forEach()` and if the id will match you can update `chatLike` array with `push()` to add a new `newLike` object.

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = [
  {
    idChatPublic: "1",
    message: "hello",
    chatLike: [
      {
        id: "1",
        idChatPublic: "1",
      },
    ],
  },
];

function updateChatLike() {
  return data.map((d) => {
    return {
      ...d,
      chatLike: [
        ...d.chatLike,
        {
          id: 2,
          idChatPublic: "2",
        },
      ],
    };
  });
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(updateChatLike(), null, 4));
```

I have used JSON.stringify() to log complete nested object

Output

```
[
    {
        "idChatPublic": "1",
        "message": "hello",
        "chatLike": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "idChatPublic": "1"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "idChatPublic": "2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Map is not necessary here in your case.

Try this.

```js
const data = [{
  idChatPublic: "1",
  message: "hello",
  chatLike: [{
    id: "1",
    idChatPublic: "1"
  }]
}];
console.log("before " , data);
sendLike(1);

console.log("after " , data);
function sendLike(messageId) {
 const newLike = {
   idChatPublic: messageId,
 }
 // mutateMessages((data) => {
    data.forEach((message) => {
    //console.log(message.idChatPublic);
      if (message.idChatPublic == messageId) {
        message.chatLike.push(newLike);
      }
    });
  //});

}
```